# IllegalArgumentException View Not Attached to Window

Tags: android, dialog, illegalargumentexception

I have an application that crashes upon restart because it immediately displays a dialog.  This only happens when I reboot the device (the application has a Boot receiver), otherwise, just starting the app on its own, it works fine.  The dialog is called by the main activity.  Here is the code:

```
public class AssistekAlertDialog extends Dialog {

    @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    ///Exception^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager)con.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keylock = manager.newKeyguardLock(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keylock.disableKeyguard();

    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:383)
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:74)
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.Dialog.onWindowAttributesChanged(Dialog.java:677)
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.Window.setType(Window.java:637)
03-05 15:38:08.292: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.assistek.ediary.AssistekAlertDialog.onAttachedToWindow(AssistekAlertDialog.java:298)
```

I can get rid of the exceptions by using a try-catch block, but that seems lazy.  Is there any other way to handle this exception?

Comment: only if(yourDialog!=null) where You using the dialog...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs That didn't seem to help.

Comment: What if you move the code from `onAttachedToWindow()` to `onCreateView()`? The latter method should fire after the windows attachment process has completed.

Comment: @DerGolem - this is not a fragment, it's an activity.

Comment: So, use `onCreate()`, instead?